# generate a P2SH-P2WSH address and spend output sent to it

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, signature, p2wsh

I am attempting generate a **P2SH-P2WSH** address and then spend an output sent to this address, but when I attempt signing I receive ***Invalid private key*** error from **bitcoind** (v0.15.1.0). So where am I going wrong I am not entirely sure that I **generate address correctly** or that **bitcoind rpc methods correctly support segwit signing operation**. 
I would appreciate if someone could confirm whether address is generated correctly or if I am somehow failing at signing stage from my end. I can provide generation code (written in Java) if needed.

Here's what I came up with:

**Address generation** 2 of 2 multisig:

```
Private hex Key c3accc350d70d1981c4366fd6fd86d9cc311048ae8620dac0b3dc9d18ce415fa
Public Key 320ce424c6d61f352ccfea60d209651672cfb03b2dc77d1d64d3ba519aec756ae

Private hex Key 1093e97f3c01bd766473cc51441d443e9325a59387421a9e2fb69b7f9587d915
Public Key 20b020e27e49f049eac10010506499a84e1d59a500cd3680e9ded580df9a107b0

Witness program=2 PUSHDATA(33)[020b020e27e49f049eac10010506499a84e1d59a500cd3680e9ded580df9a107b0] PUSHDATA(33)[0320ce424c6d61f352ccfea60d209651672cfb03b2dc77d1d64d3ba519aec756ae] 2 CHECKMULTISIG
Witness hex=5221020b020e27e49f049eac10010506499a84e1d59a500cd3680e9ded580df9a107b0210320ce424c6d61f352ccfea60d209651672cfb03b2dc77d1d64d3ba519aec756ae52ae

redeemScript program=0 PUSHDATA(32)[16a91e58e02069f95ea6defba7436199658573c34d384c69779779f4500d7cac]
redeemScript hex=002016a91e58e02069f95ea6defba7436199658573c34d384c69779779f4500d7cac

scriptPubKey program=HASH160 PUSHDATA(20)[035e0a0739eec3c195f9dc0d8b85e6e3f6ae1ece] EQUAL
scriptPubKey hex=a914035e0a0739eec3c195f9dc0d8b85e6e3f6ae1ece87

TestNetAddress=2MsZ2fpGKUydzY62v6trPHR8eCx5JTy1Dpa
```

I created these using bitcoinj library I am **not** entirely sure that this is correct, but from the look of it seemed like it was described in segwit dev guide by bitcoin core.

**Fund deposit**
I sent to this address test coins (**Testnet3**) with this TX = 122831a5cc3d3875cadd89e2a2690c2e5bc9e703d177385e1a3318a44675b6d6

**Creating raw transaction**:

```
Created transaction hex (using bitcoin rpc) = 
{
    "jsonrpc": "1.0",
    "id": "reqId1",
    "method": "createrawtransaction",
    "params": [
        [
            {
                "txid": "122831a5cc3d3875cadd89e2a2690c2e5bc9e703d177385e1a3318a44675b6d6",
                "vout": 1
            }
        ],
        {
            "mmZFY7b7NArkrnri43RwxL58m6TZUqty4t": "0.09999"
        },
        0
    ]
}
Response hex = 0200000001d6b67546a418331a5e3877d103e7c95b2e0c69a2e289ddca75383dcca53128120100000000ffffffff0198929800000000001976a914423ffad905158d1d472f5fcd5fbc6916c2fb031f88ac00000000
```

**Signing raw transaction**:

```
SignRaw transaction request (using bitcoin rpc) = {"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"signrawtransaction_1510651375833","method":"signrawtransaction","params":["0200000001d6b67546a418331a5e3877d103e7c95b2e0c69a2e289ddca75383dcca53128120100000000ffffffff0198929800000000001976a914423ffad905158d1d472f5fcd5fbc6916c2fb031f88ac00000000",[{"txid":"122831a5cc3d3875cadd89e2a2690c2e5bc9e703d177385e1a3318a44675b6d6","vout":1,"scriptPubKey":"a914035e0a0739eec3c195f9dc0d8b85e6e3f6ae1ece87","redeemScript":"002016a91e58e02069f95ea6defba7436199658573c34d384c69779779f4500d7cac","amount":"0.10000000"}],["c3accc350d70d1981c4366fd6fd86d9cc311048ae8620dac0b3dc9d18ce415fa","1093e97f3c01bd766473cc51441d443e9325a59387421a9e2fb69b7f9587d915"]]}
{
    "jsonrpc": "1.0",
    "id": "reqId2",
    "method": "signrawtransaction",
    "params": [
        "0200000001d6b67546a418331a5e3877d103e7c95b2e0c69a2e289ddca75383dcca53128120100000000ffffffff0198929800000000001976a914423ffad905158d1d472f5fcd5fbc6916c2fb031f88ac00000000",
        [
            {
                "txid": "122831a5cc3d3875cadd89e2a2690c2e5bc9e703d177385e1a3318a44675b6d6",
                "vout": 1,
                "scriptPubKey": "a914035e0a0739eec3c195f9dc0d8b85e6e3f6ae1ece87",
                "redeemScript": "002016a91e58e02069f95ea6defba7436199658573c34d384c69779779f4500d7cac",
                "amount": "0.10000000"
            }
        ],
        [
            "cN8vhcMrmcf3fUkWeTrRNt6mmiBoqnKmuce3yNcWkUjjNNskbjbg",
            "cU94urfRuwnEpGtJiiKyGsBqbC7woGazxST1HbGYWMgfVdafKmgu"
        ]
    ]
}

Result = Error{code=-5, message='Invalid private key', data='null'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bitcoin-cli's `signrawtransaction` expects a few arguments.  You got most of them right, but forgot to add the details for redeeming the actual p2wsh part.  Specifically for p2sh(p2wsh), you'd need to provide both :

```
$ bitcoin-cli -tesnet signrawtransaction \
0200000001d6b67546a418331a5e3877d103e7c95b2e0c69a2e289ddca75383dcca53128120100000000ffffffff0198929800000000001976a914423ffad905158d1d472f5fcd5fbc6916c2fb031f88ac00000000 \
'[{"txid":"122831a5cc3d3875cadd89e2a2690c2e5bc9e703d177385e1a3318a44675b6d6","vout":1,"scriptPubKey":"A914035E0A0739EEC3C195F9DC0D8B85E6E3F6AE1ECE87","redeemScript":"002016A91E58E02069F95EA6DEFBA7436199658573C34D384C69779779F4500D7CAC","amount":0.1},{"txid":"122831a5cc3d3875cadd89e2a2690c2e5bc9e703d177385e1a3318a44675b6d6","vout":1,"scriptPubKey":"A914035E0A0739EEC3C195F9DC0D8B85E6E3F6AE1ECE87","redeemScript":"5221020B020E27E49F049EAC10010506499A84E1D59A500CD3680E9DED580DF9A107B0210320CE424C6D61F352CCFEA60D209651672CFB03B2DC77D1D64D3BA519AEC756AE52AE","amount":0.1}]' \
'["cU94urfRuwnEpGtJiiKyGsBqbC7woGazxST1HbGYWMgfVdafKmgu","cN8vhcMrmcf3fUkWeTrRNt6mmiBoqnKmuce3yNcWkUjjNNskbjbg"]'
{
  "hex": "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",
  "complete": true
}
```

Comment: So it expects the same input to be specified twice once with the regular p2sh redeem script and second time with the witness script (p2wsh). That is most certainly poorly specified in the API in this case..

Comment: Yeah also in my example I am sending private key hex byte string, not the wif represantation (facepalm)

Comment: @Kristaps I agree it's not well documented.  If you'd like some more .json examples, I have some here : https://github.com/fivepiece/witness-sig , but I think you got the hang of it.  The only "gotcha" is this p2sh(p2wsh) case.

Comment: Yeah I got the hang of it, by the way I spoke with core developers they are planning to change this a bit so it can be done in cleaner and more understandable way, we will probably see some changes for this in future releases ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the rest of us mere mortals:

So it expects the same input to be specified twice once with the regular p2sh redeem script and second time with the witness script